# Error updating values of spin button

Tags: python, gtk

I am attempting to update a spin button  input on a gtk user interface using the following code:

```
if cvt != self._cvt:

    self._cvt = cvt                         
    tcond_sp_lbl.set_value(self._cvt["tcond"])
    tsat_sp_lbl.set_value(self._cvt["tsat"])
```

and I get the following error:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The object that seems to be throwing this error is called `tsat_sbtn_lbl`.  Has anyone seen this before?  What might I be doing wrong (let me know if you need to see more)?

Edit:

Could this be because I am performing UI updates on a thread other than the one that the UI was created on?  What I don't understand is why my other updates work but not this one...

Comment: 1) What is cvt? 2) Never, NEVER interact with UI from another threads. Main event loop is not threadsafe.

Comment: Ya...that was my mistake.  Need to think this through.  cvt is just a member of the class (stores data retrieved from a server).